# Handling multiple checkboxes that have different id and functions

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

What would be the best way to put all the `checkboxes` in a single event?

Example is the code below, and I have 20 of it (from `#tcbx1`- `#tcbx20`).

```
function tblcheckboxes(){
    var a=0;
    if ($('#tcbx1').is(":checked")) {
         a = parseFloat($("#tcbx1").val(), 10);
    }

$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#tcbx1').click(function(){
            tblcheckboxes();
            grandtotal();
        });
});
```

And another checkbox that has a different `id` and different `$(document).ready(function(){` (from `#cbx3`- `#cbx5`)

```
function grandtotal(){
    var g=0;
    if ($('#cbx3').is(":checked")) {
        g = parseFloat($("#cbx3").val(), 10);
        }

$(document).ready(function(){   
    $('#cbx3').click(function(){
        grandtotal();
});
```

The first `checkbox` is grouped in a single table and the other `checkbox` are just some add-ons.

Comment: Use class instead of id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [starts-with selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attr_begin.asp) `[id^="tcbx"]` to select all elements with an id starting with "tcbx".

```
function tblcheckboxes(cb){
    var a=0;
    if (cb.is(":checked")) {
        a = parseFloat(cb.val(), 10);
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[id^="tcbx"]').click(function(){
        var cb = $(this);
        tblcheckboxes(cb);
        grandtotal(cb);
    });
});
```

...and to select item starting with "cbx":

```
function grandtotal(cb){
    var g=0;
    if (cb.is(":checked")) {
        g = parseFloat(cb.val(), 10);
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){   
    $('[id^=cbx]').click(function(){
        var cb = $(this);
        grandtotal(cb);
});
```

Comment: can I also do that for the 
`if ($('#cbx3').is(":checked")) {
        g = parseFloat($("#cbx3").val(), 10);
        }`???

Comment: You can, but it might be a little different to what you have in your question. I'll update my answer.

Comment: thank you so much. it is a great help. i have just started jqueries and is doing a self-study about this, that's why I'm still not familiar with this kind of stuff.

Comment: The good this about jQuery is that its selectors are pretty much identical to CSS selectors, so a lot of the knowledge is transferable to CSS.

Comment: and if I have to add all the value of that checkbox and show it in a textbox... would this be correct?
`total += a;
    $('.txt7').val(total.toFixed(2));`